# Why is Netlify using an old url path and not updating to any new one?

Tags: navigation, create-react-app, netlify

I've got my portfolio site deployed with Netlify. On my portfolio I have a link to my resume which takes the user to a pdf version stored in Google Drive. Netlify linked to my old resume just fine, but I recently updated my resume and so I updated the link in my code. My site is built with Create React App and when I run npm start and run it on my local server, the new link to my updated resume works. But when I open my site on Netlify, it still uses the old link, even though I've changed the link in my code and deleted the file from Google Drive. Everything is connected okay - the changes from my local repo are pushed to the remote repo which trigger an automatic update on Netlify. But despite this, Netlify still uses the old link.

I've already tried re-uploading my site, using Netlify's "clear cache and retry with latest branch commit" option, using a different web browser, and using a different device, but same problem and nothing has worked yet.

What could be causing this weird behavior?

[Netlify log showing updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhQr7.jpg)

[link to old, deleted resume on Google Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PkNA.png)

[Correct resume link when accessed via localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iigUB.png)

Comment: Do you upload your react app manually by ```npm build``` or from Github in Netlify? If it is manually uploaded may be your Netlify app is not getting the updated version of React app or your new google drive pdf URL is not public; otherwise, no issues can arise in this scenario.

Comment: I initially imported it as an existing project from my GitHub, and now whenever I push changes the master remote branch, I can see Netlify tracking all of them and continuously updating my website. I updated some images today, and the changes were immediately reflected in Netlify's version. Now, I've even uploaded my resume PDF to OneDrive and changed the link to direct there, but I still get taken to the old Google Drive link, even though changes work fine in local version. I want to say it's some kind of caching issue on Netlify, but I don't know enough about this side of things to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason after going through various forums and finding a crucial bit of advice. I downloaded a zipfile of the lates version of my Netlify site to see what files were being used and I noticed a _redirects file that I completely forgot about. I had to make this file to make my redirects work when I initailly uploaded my site. I was only updating my resume redirect link with the new url in my Redirects component, but not in my _redirects file, which still had the old url, which is what Netlify looks at. After updating _redirects link, everything works as expected